# How to rename products images for more SEO-friendly

Tags: product-images

I want to rename all my products images for a better SEO-friendly.

1. Is it a good idea ?
2. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, thats good idea.

1. Name Your Images Descriptively and in Plain English
2. Optimize Your Alt Tags Intelligently

   - Alt tags are a text alternative to images when a browser can't properly render them.
     3.Strategize Your Image Dimensions and Product Angles
3. Reduce the File Sizes of Your Images
4. Use Image Site Maps

please check [here](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=YJ7bV4nLCsiL8QfH2avICg&gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+name+images+for+seo+in+ecommerce) for more information....

Comment: I know its a good idea , I mean in the magento context

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for better SEO you can do this.

You can go with existing free [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/named-images.html)

You can modify the functionality in the extension(If you want).

Hope it helps.

Comment: My store is online and it works. This extension seems to be old, it's risky :(

Comment: There is no such type of extension in the given link